# My discord.js bot's sql doesn't/cant define a table from my sqlite3 db

Tags: javascript, sqlite, discord, discord.js

Been working on this for about 3 days now and everything I've tried hasn't worked. Yes my code is/probably is sloppy but it can't seem to get the table from the data.db I have.

There is at least one table in there which has my userid and stuff, yet it definite it as undefined.

```
else{
        const pr1 = new Promise( useless => {
        sql.get(`SELECT * FROM data WHERE userid ="${message.author.id}"`)})
        .then(row => {
            if (!row) {
                sql.run("INSERT INTO data (userid, rollsleft, registered) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [message.author.id, 4, 1]);
                db.close()
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (userid INTEGER, rollsleft INTEGER, registered INTEGER)")
            .then(() => {
                sql.run("INSERT INTO data (userid, rollsleft, registered) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [message.author.id, 4, 1]);
                db.close()
            });
        });
```

There is one error I do get.

```
Error: SQLITE_RANGE: column index out of range {errno: 25, code: 'SQLITE_RANGE', stack: 'Error: SQLITE_RANGE: column index out of range', message: 'SQLITE_RANGE: column index out of range'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're slightly confused as to how `better-sqlite3` works.

First define the npm packages you are using:

```js
const database = require('better-sqlite3');
```

Now define the database and database name - this physically creates an empty database file when you run the bot.

```js
const sql = new Database('foobar.db');
```

Now it comes to adding a table to the database file.

```js
let row = sql.get('SELECT * FROM tblExample WHERE id ="${message.author.id}"').run();
//runs a select query using the table name "tblExample" byval row "id"

if(!row) { //i.e if the table "tblExample" doesnt exist (or if there are no rows that match) - in this case if you have set up the table in the right way it will be because the table doesn't exist

sql.prepare('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblExample ("id", "columns_go_here")').run();
//creates the table if it doesnt already exist
};

//then you can populate the database by using an "INSERT" statement
sql.prepare('INSERT INTO tblExample VALUES ("1111", "example")').run();

//and if you need to pull data from it use the same statement as you first used
let row = sql.get('SELECT * FROM tblExample WHERE id ="1111"').run();

//then you should be able to do
let exampleData = row.columns_go_here;
//this exampleData variable should hold the value "example" - lets console.log() it
console.log(exampleData);
//if you see "example" in your console your database is working
```

please leave a comment if you have any questions, hopefully the over commenting helped.

check out the docs [here](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/blob/HEAD/docs/api.md#class-database)